# Find predictive power through different score combinations

Tags: r, anova, lm

My situation is a bit too complex for me, given I'm a newbie in R and analysis. I have roughly nine different score types, each of which was a model itself built upon various variables for each score type. I do not have the different variables, only their resulting scores. Each person has nine scores, one from each score type. I have no additional information on these people. The dependent variable is a continuous variable from 0 to 100.

**BACKGROUND OF THE DATA:** Each score should represent the risk of a person. Generally speaking, the higher the risk, the lower their score, and vice versa. One such outcome variable that I'm looking to predict is what percentage of a loan the person has paid relative to how much they have been charged to date (i.e someone has been charged 500 dollars out of a 1000 dollar loan, and they have paid $400 of it, so their outcome is 0.8, or 80 percent.)

My goal is to see, by combining these different score types together, whether the predictive power of some outcome variable can be increased versus using just a single score type.

Now, I've already partitioned my dataset into a 70/30 training/testing data frames and I know that I need to perform some sort of regression analysis on it. Past this, I'm completely lost on how to go about getting to my goal. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I will edit as needed for additional information if this is too vague.

Edit: Here is a sample of the data

Only scoretypes 8 and 9 are categorical. The rest are continuous.

```
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| userID | scoretype1 | scoretype2 | scoretype3 | scoretype4 | scoretype5 | scoretype6 | scoretype7 | scoretype8 | scoretype9 |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|     55 |        702 |        794 |        611 |        642 |        799 |        750 |        902 | A          |         50 |
|   1239 |        731 |        792 |        613 |        689 |        887 |        645 |        872 | B          |         50 |
|   1248 |        716 |        831 |        579 |        674 |        792 |        726 |        839 | A          |         50 |
|   1371 |        812 |        857 |        658 |        823 |        843 |        715 |        964 | A          |         50 |
|   1509 |        710 |        708 |        593 |        595 |        811 |        525 |        831 | A          |         50 |
|   1613 |        709 |        756 |        601 |        619 |        886 |        465 |        853 | B          |         50 |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: It does seem too vague.  You have posited a situation in which you want to predict one outcome based on six explanatory variables, *but that's all you have told us.*  Answering that would require several monographs just to mention all the possibilities!

Comment: Would trying to find the interaction between these explanatory variables on the dependent variable be a better way of stating it, or would that be something completely different from my original question?

Comment: That would start to narrow it, but you ought to share more information, such as the nature of the data, the amount of data, any remarks on interesting or unusual characteristics, and so forth.

Comment: I did mention that the exploratory variables are score types, each being created from a different methodology. Is that not enough to describe them?

Comment: I'm afraid not, because "score" and "methodology" could cover just about anything.  At best, it leads us to suspect your explanatory variables might be correlated (but we can't even be sure of that).

Comment: Edited. Please advise if that's good enough.

Comment: Do you have any additional information about your subjects and the scores? For instance, person demographics? What is the dependent variable? Do the scores have some sequential or temporal relationship? If so, what is the time frame? Etc...etc...

Comment: Edited, additional info added in first paragraph.

Comment: Do you have *any idea at all* what the scores are supposed to mean? For example, are they more likely to represent a mental ability than the results of a blood test? Likewise, do you have *any idea at all* what the outcome variable of interest represents?